# How to allow the user to preview an image before saving and give them the ability to cancel

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am using this to store an image:

```
 var screenshot: UIImage {
  return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
   drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
  }
 }

 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(view.screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

This will save an image to Photos, but I want to allow the user to look at the photo before saving, and give them the option to cancel.

Comment: create a `PreviewViewController` and pass your image to that controller to show it to user. Add `save and cancel` button. on save button click, call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` and on cancel button click, dont do anything and just dismiss the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension RPPreviewViewController {

 convenience init(image: UIImage) {
  self.init()

  view = UIImageView(image: image)
  view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

  let cancel = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 45))
  cancel.setTitleColor(.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
  cancel.setTitle("Cancel", for: UIControl.State.normal)
  cancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  cancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(canceled), for: .touchUpInside)

  view.addSubview(cancel)
 }


 @objc func canceled() {
  print("cancel")
 }

}
```

To use:

```
let preview = RPPreviewViewController(image: view.screenshot)
present(preview, animated: true, completion: nil)
```